# jquery validation plugin inline custom rule

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I created a custom rule

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test-form").validate({
            rules: { 
                test1:{
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                } 
            },
            messages:  {
                test1:{
                    required: "required",
                minlength: "min 2"                      
                }
            }
        });
    // don't really process form
    $("#test-form").submit(function() { return false; });
```

and I have this HTML code

```
<input type="text" class="test1"/>
```

however it doesn't work

if I change to predefined rule , it works

```
<input type="text" class="number"/>
```

Comment: `Validate()` uses the `name=` attribute from your `input`, but you don't have one.  Add a `name="test1"` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The keys in `rules` should match the `name` parameter of the field. Try this:

```
<input type="text" name="test1" />
```

Also, you can use `debug: true` in the options of validate to prevent the form submission while you're testing, instead of returning false from the form submit.

Answer (score 1):

Rory is right, the rules and messages key should match the 'name' attribute however it looks although you're attempting to create a custom rule which can be added declaratively via a class name?

I think you're therefore looking for the [`.addMethod()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage) function which can be used like this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("alphanumeric", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^\w+$/i.test(value);
}, "Letters, numbers, and underscores only please");
```

Which will automatically get picked up via a class name like this:

```
<input type="text" class="alphanumeric" />
```